# Symfony2 subform names

Tags: forms, post, symfony, subform

How do I give a subform a name so it will send it's data in the respective post key?
In The following example the name for the main form is "form" and the name of both subforms is also "form", which results in only one subform beeing displayed. the post data looks like this:

```
form[form][amount]=
form[form][value]=
```

In this sample code `$mainForm`, `$subForm1` and `$subForm2` are instances of `FormBuilder`.

```
$subForm1->add('amount', 'text');
$subForm1->add('value', 'text');
$mainForm->add($subForm1);

$subForm2->add('amount', 'text');
$subForm2->add('value', 'text');
$mainForm->add($subForm2);
```

So How can I change it send the post data like following?

```
form[subForm1][amount]=
form[subForm1][value]=
form[subForm2][amount]=
form[subForm2][value]=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you creating your `FormBuilders`?

If you're using the `FormFactory`, you can use the `createNamed()` or `createNamedBuilder()` methods on the factory to set a name.

Alternatively, you can call `$mainForm->create($name)` to create a named form (note that all that does is call `$mainForm`'s Factory and does not automatically add it to `$mainForm`.